# Repairing Windows 8 after trying to dual boot it with Fedora 18

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, fedora, multi-boot

As the title states, I turned off secure boot and installed fedora 18 as usual using a liveUSB installer. This seems to have really miffed windows and now it refuses to boot.

Grub2 comes up fine, I see the Windows 8 loader entry there and fedora is there. I can boot into fedora just fine, but when I try too boot into Windows 8, I'm met with an error:

`Boot configuration file is missing. Repair using install media.`

The error code I get is `0xc0000225.`

I've tried following a lot of guides online, but none of them seems to be dealing with my type of problem.

I tried automatic fixing. It didn't work.

I've tried using bootrec using the command prompt on a usb recovery disk. It didn't help.
( I followed the instructions [here](http://www.techspot.com/guides/630-windows-8-boot-fix/) )

Running bcdedit gives me

`The boot congiguration data store could not be opened. The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.`

The partitions, Windows8 OS partition and the Recovery partition are both there. (I checked using gparted) so the OS hasn't been over-written.

I'd like to know if I can repair the bootloader to show and boot both windows and Fedora?

Comment: Fedora was the first Linux distro AFAIK to include Secure Boot support using shim, so I advise you to re-enable SB, see if Win8 boots, if not repair it so it hopefully does, then get rid of the Fedora partitions and try to reinstall [with SB](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SecureBoot).

Comment: Repairing Windows is the primary part I need help with.

Comment: Try the same procedure you used before with bootrec, but *after* you've re-enabled Secure Boot. I feel disabling that is what is causing Win8 (and Win8 repair) to choke.

Comment: I can't boot through a USB when secure boot is enabled. Infact I can't boot into anything when secure boot is enabled. I can't boot windows, can't boot via pendrive to repair it can can't boot into Fedora. It sort-of goes into a loop and starts asking me which medium I would like to use to boot. None of them works though.

Comment: Hmm, well booting from USB *should* be possible even with SB enabled, by going through the UEFI shell's options, but there are so many different UEFI implementations out there by different motherboard manufacturers that one can't really provide generic advice. Also at this point it's not really clear whether the damage can be undone, so perhaps a complete nuke and redo might be in order. If you have a Win8 DVB/USB you should try to boot in UEFI mode and install it after nuking all partitions, then proceed with Fedora if that succeeds. Or use the recovery option first if that's available.

Comment: Would it be possible to move this discussion to the chat?

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8770/repairing-windows-8-after-trying-to-dual-boot-it-with-fedora-18

It will be faster, and will not turn the question into a discussion thread.

Comment: I guess the chat Idea didn't work out. About your suggestion to boot with a Win8 USB in UEFI mode, I can't seem to do that. I.e My laptop basically refuses to boot anything in UEFI mode.

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to get notified regarding your previous comment. I suggest adding @name somewhere to ensure that happens. To be perfectly honest though not sure a chat will help anyway. UEFI's still new and even with old BIOSes the quirks are so many that often only prior knowledge of the exact model's options or physical access to the system helps. Did you format the USB stick as FAT32? UEFI implementations to date can't handle NTFS. Also, did you mention your laptop model anywhere? A look at the manual *might* help, but often they include just a very cursory explanation of the BIOS options.

Comment: P.S. I hope you tried your UEFI booting experiments both with Secure Boot turned on and off? Also hope you tried the Win8 DVD too and not just the USB. Ensure you insert the DVD/USB and then enter the UEFI shell to select the boot device. If possible also post camera snaps of the boot menu and related options, when the system is booted with the DVD/USB inserted. If using a FAT32 USB (use Rufus to create it from the Win8 ISO), try both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports if they're available. (Clutching at straws, but who knows what might just work! :)

Comment: Yes, I tried the UEFI with both Secure boot on and off. I don't have a DVD drive in my laptop, so I can't use a DVD :( . I'll try using both USB 2.0 and 3.0, not sure how much that'll change things though.